# Get digit from filename immediately preceeding file extension, with other digits in filename

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to extract the last number before a file extension in a bash script. So the format varies but it'll be some combination of numbers and letters, and the last character will always be a digit. I need to pull those digits and store them in a variable.

The format is generally:

```
sdflkej10_sdlkei450_sdlekr_1.txt
```

I want to store just the final digit 1 into a variable.

I'll be using this to loop through a large number of files, and the last number will get into double and triple digits.

So for this file:

```
kej10_sdlkei450_sdlekr_310.txt
```

I'd need to return 310.

The number of alphanumeric characters and underscores varies with each file, but the number I want always is immediately before the .txt extension and immediately after an underscore.

I tried:

```
bname=${f%%.*}
number=$(echo $bname | tr -cd '[[:digit:]]')
```

but this returns all digits.

If I try

```
number = $(echo $(bname -2) it changes the number it returns.
```

The problem i'm having is mostly related to the variability, and the fact that I've been asked to do it in bash. Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: When you say you have to "do it in bash", does that mean you aren't allowed to use command line versions of utilities like perl or sed?

Comment: I'm allowed to use sed, but not perl. I'm basically not allowed to use things that absolutely everyone on the project can use. Sed, awk, bash are pretty much it.

Answer (score 2):

```
regex='([0-9]+)\.[^.]*$'
[[ $file =~ $regex ]] && number=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

This uses bash's underappreciated `=~` regex operator which stores matches in an array named `BASH_REMATCH`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using parameter substitution

```
var=kej10_sdlkei450_sdlekr_310.txt
var=${var%.*}
var=${var##*_}
echo $var
310
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use a Series of Bash Shell Expansions

While not the most elegant solution, this one uses a sequence of [shell parameter expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to achieve the desired result without having to define a specific extension. For example, this function uses the length and offset expansions to find the digit after removing filename extensions:

```
extract_digit() {
    local basename=${1%%.*}
    echo "${basename:$(( ${#basename} - 1 ))}"
}
```

### Capturing Function Output

You can capture the output in a variable with something like:

```
$ foo=$(extract_digit sdflkej10_sdlkei450_sdlekr_1.txt)
$ echo $foo
1
```

### Sample Output from Function

```
$ extract_digit sdflkej10_sdlkei450_sdlekr_1.txt
1

$ extract_digit sdflkej10_sdlkei450_sdlekr_9.txt
9

$ extract_digit sdflkej10_sdlkei450_sdlekr_10.txt
0
```

Answer (score 0):

This should take care of your situation:

```
INPUT="some6random7numbers_12345_moreletters_789.txt"
SUBSTRING=`expr match "$INPUT" '.*_\([[:digit:]]*\)'`
echo $SUBSTRING
```

This will output `789`

Answer (score 0):

No need of regex here, you can utilize [`IFS`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html)

```
var="kej10_sdlkei450_sdlekr_310.txt"
v=$(IFS=[_.] read -ra arr <<< "$var" && echo "${arr[@]:(-2):1}")
echo "$v"
310
```